# Retrieve date data from browser

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, cgi, query-string

I am doing web application and I cannot retrieve a date value from the browser. I have selected the date 01/16/2014.

The query string looks like:

```
?dd=01%2F16%2F2014
```

and my code is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound 
import cgi, cgitb 

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
def pod_available(request):
    dat = form.getvalue('dd')
    print dat
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>Hello<em>" + str(dat) + "</em></body></html>")
```

Output:

```
HelloNone
```

Comment: What calls `pod_available`? What type of object is `request`?

Comment: yes its request object. Its python web application.

Comment: But `cgi` scripts don't **have** a `request` object, nor do they have a `HttpResponse()` class. You have not shared all your code; where do `request` and `HttpResponse` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Django application, then using CGI in any way makes absolutely no sense. I assume that `pod_available` is being called with a [`HttpRequest`](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/HttpRequest) object passed to it, so if you want to read the request data, you have to access that object to get it.

You can do that by accessing they key—`'dd'` in this case—of the object:

```
def pod_available(request):
    dat = request['dd']
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>Hello<em>" + str(dat) + "</em></body></html>")
```

In any way, this is not a CGI application, so don’t use any CGI stuff in there.

Comment: yes.. i need a dd value from HTTP request.

Comment: @NikunjGami Uhm, so… does it work when you do `request.getvalue('dd')` instead of `form.getvalue('dd')`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a Django application, **you are not using CGI**. The `forms` variable will only be filled *once*, and will forever be empty. You may as well remove the `cgi` and `cgitb` module imports, they are of no use to you here.

You need to re-read the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial04/); the `request` parameter to your view contains all your form variables:

```
def pod_available(request):
    dat = request.GET['dd']
    print dat
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>Hello<em>" + str(dat) + "</em></body></html>")
```

The [`request.GET` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) is a dictionary holding the request parameters passed in via the URL.

Comment: oh dear... i just mismatch two application.. Thanks for reminds me.